# inputting array of characters in c

Tags: c++, c, arrays, character

I have written this code to input two array of characters `a` and `b` of size `5` each.

When I give the input :

```
abcde
abcde
```

the output `b[2]` should be `c` but it is giving as `b`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

   char a[5], b[5];
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
       scanf("%c", a + i);
   }

   for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
       scanf("%c", b + i);
   }

    printf("%c", b[2]);
}
```

Comment: Then how  i avoid this

Comment: Pick a language. C doesn't **have** `namespace std`, and in C++ you'd use `std::cin >>`

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing `abcde` for the first `scanf`? This character is consumed by the second `scanf` during the first iteration of the second `for` loop.

You can fix it by adding

```
scanf("%*c");
```

or

```
getchar();
```

between the two `for` loops. This will scan and discard the newline character.

Comment: Or, better yet, if your input consists of lines, use an input function that reads lines.